# How to pass information from lambda back to my app (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm developing a messaging mobile application and are currently using the ionic framework + AWS. My question is how can I pass back the information from lambda function back to my mobile application? I tried to use an API gateway but when I call the api gateway from the app the lambda function will trigger again and the information from the DynamoDB Streams in the lambda function will be overriden. (See picture). Is there a way that I can pass it back with api gateway without the information to be overiden? Like just a GET request that gets the current information without passing in anything. 
Here's my architecture.[App Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmk91.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the API Gateway to deliver an SNS message which then calls the Lambda function, you can configure the Lambda function trigger to be the **API Gateway itself**.

You can find instructions on how to link two in the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html#getting-started-new-get)

When used this way, the result of the Lambda function will be the response to the HTTP call.

Comment: You mean that I skip the use of SNS entirely?

Comment: Exactly. Just configure API gateway and use an HTTP endpoint to invoke the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lambda Proxy Integration with API Gateway.  The Lambda will be like a HTTP end point.  You will be able to create the Response object in your Lambda. Your App will get it as Payload.

[AWS Lambda Proxy Integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html)

Comment: But then my lambda functin will still be overriden? because it will be triggered so the information from the DynamoDB Streams will be overriden when I call the lambda function?

Comment: If you want to push response to your App, you cannot achieve it with just Lambda.  You may want to look at IOT which supports WebSocket over HTTP.